# Distinguish between renamed .accde file and .accdb file

Tags: ms-access

I have been given an Access database .accdb file by a client to work with.  When I open it and try to open a code or form design window, it reports that it is an .accde file (with no code).  Is there a way (with a hex editor, for example) that I can prove to my client that this is a renamed .accde file, not an .accdb?

Comment: With an actual ACCDE, attempting to open a module from the Navigation pane triggers the error *"You can't import, export, create, modify, or rename any forms, reports, pages or modules in an ACCDE, MDE or ADE database."*  Isn't that proof enough?

Comment: Well, my client was assured by the original developer that the file was an .accdb and could be used for development.  I got the 'you can't...' message already, I'd just like some hard proof.

Answer (score 0):

- Make a copy of the original file, and save it as an accde file.
- Create a new small database with just a splash screen and save it as an accdb file.
- Copy that file, and then convert it to an accde file.
- Schedule a 15 minute meeting with your boss and show him all 4 files.

Unless he just fell off a turnip truck, he's going to see the difference between when an accdb and accde file open (i.e. your newly created files), and see that the original accdb file opens with the exact same message as your accde copy and your newly created accde.

If he can't put 2 and 2 together, schedule a meeting with his supervisor and ask for his job.